# Show color by dot density

Tags: applications, grayscale

Suppose I have a grayscale image and I want to translate the image into a black and white image (bw-image) in the following way:

- white color = no black dots in the bw-image
- ...in between....
- black color = very high black dot density

Is that understandable? Is there a program, preferably open-source, that is able to achieve this task?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26554/dither-a-grayscale-image which shows some approaches to dithering a grayscale image into a black-and-white image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate a halftone image like this:
[image: halftone]

If so, there are a number of applications and plugins that you can use.

- It can be done in Photoshop, using either the built in Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone or through changing the image mode to bitmap and [using a halftone screen](http://creativepro.com/how-to-make-amazing-halftone-effects-with-photoshop/).
- It can be done in illustrator with the [color halftone filter](http://vectips.com/tutorials/creating-halftone-effects/) or with the [Phantasm](http://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/) plugin (paid)
- [The rasterbator](http://rasterbator.net/) allows you to convert an image to halftone online
- [GIMP](http://theamateurdesigner.blogspot.se/2011/08/how-to-make-halftones-with-gimp-and.html) can create halftones using the Newsprint filter
- [Inkscape](http://theamateurdesigner.blogspot.se/2011/08/how-to-make-halftones-with-gimp-and.html) can also create haltone effects using the tiled clones function.